# Android - ID unique to the installation of an app

Tags: android

Is there an ID available that is unique to the installation of an app?

Unique across devices I mean, so if the same app is installed on 10 different devices then there are 10 different ids.  And two different apps on the same device must give two different IDs.

Needs to remain constant following app updates and would ideally change if you uninstalled and reinstalled the app.

And for security reasons I don't want to generate a UUID and write it to a file in app-private storage.

Comment: There is. You may use [this library](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib) to generate an ID that does exactly what you want: [Identity.getInstallationId(context)](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib/blob/master/Source/src/im/delight/android/baselib/Identity.java).

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't meet the criteria.  I said "_for security reasons I don't want to generate a UUID and write it to a file in app-private storage_" but the 'writeInstallationId' method does exactly that

Comment: Well, that does only have security implications on rooted devices, right? If that's a concern, okay. Then you can't use any app-specific identifier, most certainly, and you must use a device identifier.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this is to make use of the Android SharedPreferencesBackupHelper class and the BackupAgentHelper.  No need to store your UUID in a file in app-private storage (though I'm not sure what your security constraints are, so using the SharedPreferences database might not be any better).  This solution allows you to have a device/installation-unique ID, and it will survive through app uninstall and install (which I generally think of as a good thing).  If you have your app make a determination at run-time if it has been re-installed, then the app can generate a new UUID at that time.

One way of doing this is to look in your app's installed resource bundle for an indicator file that is part of your .apk.  If the app sees this file, it's a new install: generate/store the UUID then delete the file (or alter its content).  Subsequent executions will find this and realize that it's not a new install.

Does that meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks, but no - I was hoping that there would be an ID that Android would give me.  I don't want to persist it in orefs or on disk for some slightly strange security reasons.

Comment: @PaulHilliar I think you're giving yourself an impossible task.  What you're looking for, an "installation fingerprint" that Android knows and can give to your app on demand, but is not knowable by other apps on-board.  But Android itself has to be able to persist it so it can be provided on demand.I don't think an ID exists that fits your parameters.

Comment: Yes 'installation fingerprint' exactly what I would want - that's a good name for it.  It's perfectly feasible that Android would provide such an ID, just a little annoying that they have chosen not to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides an [Advertising ID](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html) as a unique identifier across all devices/users and works across all Google Play devices API 9 or higher.

There are a number of other mechanisms, such as using the [Settings.SECURE.ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) as detailed in [this (pre-advertising ID) blog post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID). Note the comments from the blog post on `ANDROID_ID` though:

> There are downsides: First, it is not 100% reliable on releases of Android prior to 2.2 (“Froyo”). Also, there has been at least one widely-observed bug in a popular handset from a major manufacturer, where every instance has the same ANDROID_ID.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the advertising ID the same for all apps on the same device/user?  I want to identify the app installation.  Two different apps on the same device must give two different IDs

Comment: So prepend the package name to the advertising ID and it'll be unique across each app.

Comment: That works as an ID but I hoped there would be something not easily knowable to other apps on the phone

Comment: You probably need to explain your use case some more as I'm having a hard time figure out why 1) you need a unique device id 2) why it needs to be unique across every app/user combination 3) why there's a security concern. It doesn't seem like you should be relying on anything created by a client (or a malicious app personating your app) from a security perspective.